# What is the best practice to clone a ng-template content into document.body in Angular 11?

Tags: angular, templates, clone, clonenode

I have a deeply embedded component in my Angular project. The parent elements has some `ngIf` conditions, so this component not always showed.

If the component is present in the DOM and it is visible on the screen I want to make it a sticky-like element. When the user scroll this element under a specified top pixel I need to change it to sticky.

I tried to apply `cloneNode()` like this:

```js
  @ViewChild('optionBox') optionBox: ElementRef;

  @HostListener('body:scroll', ['$event'])
  onScroll(event: Event): void {

    if (this.showOptionBox) {
      const positionTop = this.optionBox.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY;

      // 90 is the height of header
      if (positionTop < 60 && !this.optionBoxClone) {
        this.optionBoxClone = this.optionBox.nativeElement.cloneNode(true);
        this.optionBoxClone.style.position = 'fixed';
        this.optionBoxClone.style.top = 90 + 'px';
        this.optionBoxClone.style.left = this.optionBox.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().left + 'px';
        this.optionBoxClone.style.zIndex = '10000';
        // document.body.appendChild(this.optionBoxClone);
      }

      // remove clone if the original element becambe visible under the clone
      if (positionTop > 65 && !!this.optionBoxClone) {
        this.optionBoxClone?.remove();
        this.optionBoxClone = null;
      }
    }
  }
```

This solution is create the clone HTML elements as I expect, but scripted functions not works.

Next I tried to use the `ng-template` with `TemplateRef`:

```html
  <ng-template #clone>
    ... my HTML code what I wan to clone
  </ng-template>

  <!-- I want to clone here the template for non-sticky behavior -->
  <div #optionContainer></div>
```

And the TypeScript code is:

```js
  @ViewChild('clone') template: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('body', {read: ViewContainerRef}) container: ViewContainerRef;
  @ViewChild('optionContainer', {read: ViewContainerRef}) optionContainer: ViewContainerRef;

  @HostListener('body:scroll', ['$event'])
  onScroll(event: Event): void {

    if (this.showOptionBox) {
      const positionTop = this.optionBox.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY;

      // 90 is the height of header
      if (positionTop < 60 && !this.optionBoxClone) {
        // ...css tricks
        this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
      }
    }
  }
```

But here the `@ViewChild('body', ...` part not works ofcourse.

So what is the best practie to clone a ng-template content into document.body in Angular 11? I want to use all functions in my component in the cloned element too.

Comment: why not use `position: sticky; top: 0;` in your css?

Comment: because a parent has `position: relative` setting and I can't break this rule

Comment: try this: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3737-rendering-a-templateref-as-a-child-of-the-body-element-in-angular-9-0-0-rc-5.htm, with the concept in https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/9d6e62b548a7bce799f604188a4502163a280e50/src/util/positioning.ts#L105